# Analog of simplicial sets for space gluing from arbitrary convex polyhedra

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, polyhedra, simplicial-complex

We can describe a space gluing from simplices as simplicial set.

When space is gluing from cubes there is notion of cubical set.

What is about some other class of polyhedra? What is known in this direction?

So my space is somehow glued from convex polyhedra. Can I describe it as a functor from some category to the category of sets?

I want to describe what is the problem.

In the case of simplicial set we choose some canonical representative of a simplex in any direction. Then we choose canonical identification of a face of n-dimensional simplex with standard (n-1)-th dimensional simplex. There are degeneracy maps as well. And all these maps should satisfy some identities.

However it is not clear how to identify a face with some standard polyhedra, this identification in general even cannot be affine.

Comment: I would say yes, considering you have a definite ordering of your vertices?

Comment: Can you please explain more details?

Comment: The construction of simplicial sets is based on totally ordered sets to orientate the edges of your simplicial sets, so it would be natural to require an ordering fitting the structure of your polyhedron, or polyhedra

Comment: I described the difficulties that I had. If you want to order the set of vertices then no problem. But I think that the structure should be more complicated because in our case the automorphism group of polyhedra wouldn't acts on the set of all ordering transitively.

Comment: Maybe we should use ordering, but not total. Something like ordered trees?

Comment: Yes, not a complete ordering